# how can i make this work href with onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

How can i make this work.

```
<a href="#" onClick="javascript.functiontoget$date();">'.$date.'</a>
```

the $date value is inside the while loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$date = $row['Date'];
echo '<tr class="normalRow"><td><a href="#" onClick="javascript.functiontoget$date();">$date</a></td></tr>;'
    }
```

Comment: Do mean `onclick`? Also, please add details to the question, it's unclear of what you are asking.

Comment: `javascript.functiontoget$date();` is what? What is supposed to work? Is the issue with JavaScript or PHP?

Comment: @AndrewL. i want to run a function when i click the $date, that it will get the value of that $date and run another query

Comment: @epascarello that function purpose is to get the value of that $date that was click (cause its clickable/linkable) and run a query using the value of that $date

Comment: So either stick the date inside of the method you are calling, or reference the text in the element that was clicked.

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean reference the text? and how can i do it

Answer (score 0):

Variables aren't expanded inside single-quotes strings, only double-quoted strings. You need to use concatenation.

```
echo '<tr class="normalRow"><td><a href="#" onClick="javascript.functiontoget$date();">' . $date . '</a></td></tr>;'
```

Comment: sorry i just forgot the period

Answer (score 0):

So either set the date in the method you are calling

```
onclick="foo('thedate')"
```

or reference the element that was clicked and read the text

```
onclick="foo(this)"
```

and

```
function foo(elem) { 
    alert(elem.textContent); 
}
```

---

```js
function foo1(str) {
   alert(str);  
}


function foo2(elem) {
   alert(elem.textContent);  
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="foo1('hello')">hello</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#" onclick="foo2(this)">hello</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry for this stupid question but what is foo stand for??

Comment: What ever your JavaScript function is

Comment: @epascallo i tried doing this but when i click no value was shown.

Comment: Works for me, so what is different?